# Limiting number of checked checkboxes in a google sheets column on edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to limit the number of checked checkboxes in a column to a set number (17). I've tried developing this script using the Google Apps Script but when I go into the spreadsheet and check boxes, it does not protect the range after 17.

Some important details : my first column and first two rows contain identifying information, so the checkboxes start at column 2 and row 3. Within each column, I'd like to limit the number of checkboxes to a max of 17. My last row contains COUNTIF(COLUMN CHECKBOX RANGE, TRUE) that tallies the number of checked boxes in that column, so I've tried to use this cell as my limiter.

This is my first time using this app scripter and I don't have a lot of experience in this type of programming language, so I appreciate your help and advice.

Here is the code I tried in the app scripter. It doesn't throw an error but when I check boxes in the sheet I can check more than 17 per column, so the ranges clearly aren't getting protected.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet Name'); 
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow(); // gets last row identity where countif function resides
  var lc= sheet.getLastColumn(); // gets last column
  var range = sheet.getRange(lr, 2,1,lc-1); // gets range of cell values in last row
  var data = range.getValues(); // gets values of range
  
  for(var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) // loop over length of active columns starting from column 2
  {
    var range2 = sheet.getRange(3,i,lr-2,1); // get range of cells within column i
    if( data[i] >= 17) // check if last row in column i is >= to my limit of 17
    {
      range2.protect().setDescription('reached max number of checks'); //protect row values within column i from being edited
      range2.setBackground('#f4c7c3'); // change colour of cells within column i to red
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. You haven't described a scenario (you're using an `onEdit` trigger - why?) and your references to the checkboxes and the number of `checked checkboxes`, and checkboxed in rows and columns, etc,  isn't clear at all. In short, we don't really understand what you're doing, how/why you're doing it, what you're trying to achieve and the specific problem that you are having. Would you please provide clarification about your scenario, process, goals and data/data layout (perhaps even a snapshot) to make your question/problem this more clearly focused.

Comment: On a tangent, regarding your script: #1) `for(var i = 2; i < data.length; i++)` - `data` is a one row, 2D array so `data.length` = 1; you probably want `data[0].length` (or maybe just `lc-1`). #2) `i=2`, you need to start with `i=0` (zero)- you're looping through the data array which is zero-based. #3) `sheet.getRange(3,i,lr-2,1)`-since i must start at 0 (zero), the column reference needs to be `i+2` in order to get a looped column number of 2, 3, 4, etc. #4) `data[i] >= 17` this is just wrong, but I will hold off suggesting an alternative until you clarify data layout.

Comment: @Tedinoz thanks for your response. I have a spreadsheet where each cell is a checkbox from row 3 to 27 and column 2 onward. Row 28 contains a countif function that tallies the number of checked (TRUE) checkboxes in the column. I want to limit the total number of checked boxes in each column to 17. My goal was to protect the range of cells within each column when the tally reaches 17. When a 17th box is checked and the countif cell reaches 17 I want the code to protect that column of boxes. Please let me know what is not clear in this scenario and I'll try to better clarify any details.

Comment: @Tedinoz thanks as well for your second comment, I fixed the loop and syntax around data[i] and the code executes now :) much appreciated!